# Django group by month name

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to get an output of {'month': 'jan', 'count': 1600} but I get the following with the current code {'month': 1, 'count': 1600}. How do I do this so I get the name of the month and not the integer.

```
class Month(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(MONTH from %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = IntegerField()

Note.objects.filter(
        email_status__in=status_list,
        email_template__isnull=False,
        creation_time__gt=one_year
    ).annotate(
        month=Month('creation_time')
    ).values('month').annotate(
        total_count=Count(
            'email_id', distinct=True)
    ).values('total_count', 'month')
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) instead of `EXTRACT`. The following is untested.

```
class Month(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '%%b')"
    output_field = CharField()
```

Alternatively, it shouldn't be too tricky to convert the integers 1-12 to 'jan'-'dec' in Python.